Looking for a better way to calculate a function of a list
I have a list of paired values, each pair being represented as a list, as, for example, here:
sample = {{-3, 1/3}, {2, 1/2}, {-3, 1/3}}
Each of the pairs shows a value that derives from a probability mass function (p.m.f.), together with its associated probability; so, for example, {-1, 1/3} indicates that the probability of drawing the value -3 from the p.m.f is 1/3.
The sample contains information about the probability of drawing, with replacement, from the p.m.f., the values -3, followed by 2, followed by -3. I want to efficiently calculate the mean of the drawn sample, as well as the probability of its occurrence. Currently, I have the function:
MeanAndProbability[l_]:=Module[
{
  t = Transpose[l]
},
{Mean[t[[1]]], Times @@ t[[2]]}
]

which will, correctly, return {-4/3, 1/18}.
But is there a neater way? Using Transpose followed by Parts, feels clumsy. I thought that some clever use of Outer would help, but I couldn't find a solution.
Please note that the sample size (i.e., the number of pairs involved in a list) will not necessarily be 3 and might be very large ... and ideally, I'd like the method to work with a sample size of 1 (e.g., where sample ={{-3, 1/3}}.
Timing information from some responses
Note: I'm using a vintage 2008 machine with no a great deal of memory, so it rewards improvements very well!
Generate lots of 3-samples ... it's not relevant for this exercise how long it takes!
lotsOfSamples = Table[{RandomInteger[{-10, 10}],  N[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]], 100]}, {1000000}, {3}];
Function from @vindobona
vin[s_] := Diagonal[Query[{Mean, Apply[Times]}][s]]

AbsoluteTiming[vin /@ lotsOfSamples ;]
{108.496, Null}

Function from Sjoerd Smit
smit[s_] := {Mean[s[[All, 1]]], Times @@ s[[All, 2]]}

AbsoluteTiming[smit/@ lotsOfSamples ;]
{12.6806, Null}

My function shown earlier
AbsoluteTiming[MeanAndProbability /@  lotsOfSamples ;]
{29.1395, Null}

Function from Glenn Welch
welch[s_] := 
 MapThread[Construct, {{Mean, Apply[Times]}, Transpose[s]}]

AbsoluteTiming[welch /@ lotsOfSamples ;]
{21.8928, Null}

Nice improvements ... and the function from @vindobona taught me about 2 functions I hadn't known about, as well as introducing me to the @ construction.

If you want to avoid transposing, just do {Mean[t[[All, 1]]], Times @@ t[[All, 2]]}.

@SjoerdSmit Thank you. If you write this as an answer, I will mark it correct. See timing information added into my OP.

Instead of transposing, just slice your data along the 2nd dimension with Part:
{Mean @ t[[All, 1]], Times @@ t[[All, 2]]}


This is one possibility:
sample = {{-3, 1/3}, {2, 1/2}, {-3, 1/3}};

Diagonal@Query[{Mean, Apply@Times}]@sample


{-(4/3), 1/18}


{Mean[#.{1, 0}], Times @@ #.{0, 1}} &[sample]

(* {-(4/3), 1/18} *)


Very nice. On the same machine as I tested the other routines, this actually runs the fastest (10.2 seconds for the same test ... yes, I'll add it). .. Although I find the answer by @SjoerdSmit to be more transparent. That, of course, is a matter of taste.

If you are trying to avoid Part, I believe that you are looking for something along these lines.
sample = {{-3, 1/3}, {2, 1/2}, {-3, 1/3}};

MapThread[Construct, {{Mean, Apply[Times]}, Transpose[sample]}]

(* {-(4/3), 1/18} *)


Comap is a little bit faster than Query:
Diagonal@Comap[{Mean, Apply@Times}]@sample


{-(4/3), 1/18}

